# Python - Function to skip repeat strings in list works sometimes, sometimes not

Tags: python, string, repeat

**Summary of Problem**
I am trying to build a routine that reads state abbreviations from a string, separating the abbreviations by commas. Often, states are repeated. However, I want to compile a list of every state that appears in the strings, just once. Thus, I need to skip repeated abbreviations.

**What I've Tried**
To do that, I cycle through the rows of the dataframe that contains the strings to be separated, I separate the string on commas to make a new list of state abbreviations rather than one string of them, and then I loop through that list of abbreviations. In this final loop, I do nothing if the string is already in the output list; I add the string (state abbreviation) if the string is not in the output list.
I have created a function that works on two dataframes, one simple and one more complex:

**Show Some Code**

```
import pandas as pd

#Create function to gather state abbreviations from string in dataframe
def exclude_dups_list(df):
    states_list = []    #initialize output
    for row in df.itertuples():
        current_list = [state for state in row[4].split(',')]
        for abb in current_list:
            if abb in states_list:  #If the abbreviation is already in the states_list
                #Add nothing to the list, but let user know.
                print(abb, ' already in list - skipping.')
            else:
                states_list.append(abb.strip())
                print('*----------*\n',abb, ' added to list.\n*----------*\n')
    return states_list

#Create demo dataframe
col_names = ['Cat NO.', 'Period ', 'Month', 'States ']
#Simple case - function behaves
data1 = [[1, '2/17/2017 - 3/5/2017', 'February', 'FL'], [2,'5/25/2017','May', 'FL'], [3, '6/18/2017','June','FL'], [4,'6/19/2017 - 6/21/2017', 'June', 'FL']]
#More complex case - function misbehaves, HI appears twice
data2 = [[1, '2/17/2017 - 3/5/2017', 'February', 'AZ, FL'], [2,'5/25/2017','May', 'FL, HI'], [3, '6/18/2017','June','FL, AL'], [4,'6/19/2017 - 6/21/2017', 'June', 'FL, HI, NH']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=col_names)

new_list = exclude_dups_list(df)
print(new_list)
```

If you run this with data1 in the dataframe, it behaves like I thought it would. As soon as you switch to data2 (the more complex case), it does not behave like I thought it would. When I run data2, I get multiple HI entries in the list. I thought it may have to do with different occurrences of the same abbreviation having a space before or after, so I tried to use the .strip attribute. That did not fix it. Now, I know that the function is doing exactly what it is written to do, but I would like help figuring out how to make it skip any repeated states resulting in only unique values in the output.

Comment: Since you're using `abb.strip()` to put states into the list, you should also be using `abb.strip()` to check their existence with the `in` operator.

Comment: P.S. consider using a `set` instead of a `list`, duplicates will automatically be merged without having to check anything.

Comment: @MarkRansom  yup, plus it'll be infinitely faster

Comment: I hadn't heard about sets, @MarkRansom. I will try that. I presume that there is similar code to this under the hood of any function that can create a set.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why your code isn't working as it should. But adding a `abb = abb.strip()` before u start making the comparation will guarantee that u'll only work with "correct" words.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create function to gather state abbreviations from string in dataframe
def exclude_dups_list(df):
    states_list = []    #initialize output
    for row in df.itertuples():
        current_list = [state for state in row[4].split(',')]
        for abb in current_list:
            abb = abb.strip()
            if abb in states_list:  #If the abbreviation is already in the states_list
                #Add nothing to the list, but let user know.
                print(abb, ' already in list - skipping.')
            else:
                states_list.append(abb.strip())
                print('*----------*\n',abb, ' added to list.\n*----------*\n')
    return states_list

#Create demo dataframe
col_names = ['Cat NO.', 'Period ', 'Month', 'States ']
#Simple case - function behaves
data1 = [[1, '2/17/2017 - 3/5/2017', 'February', 'FL'], [2,'5/25/2017','May', 'FL'], [3, '6/18/2017','June','FL'], [4,'6/19/2017 - 6/21/2017', 'June', 'FL']]
#More complex case - function misbehaves, HI appears twice
data2 = [[1, '2/17/2017 - 3/5/2017', 'February', 'AZ, FL'], [2,'5/25/2017','May', 'FL, HI'], [3, '6/18/2017','June','FL, AL'], [4,'6/19/2017 - 6/21/2017', 'June', 'FL, HI, NH']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=col_names)

new_list = exclude_dups_list(df)
print(new_list)
```

**Output**

*----------*
AZ  added to list.
*----------*

*----------*
FL  added to list.
*----------*

FL  already in list - skipping.

*----------*
HI  added to list.
*----------*

FL  already in list - skipping.

*----------*
AL  added to list.
*----------*

FL  already in list - skipping.

HI  already in list - skipping.

*----------*
NH  added to list.
*----------*

['AZ', 'FL', 'HI', 'AL', 'NH']

Comment: Thank you, @LuizAntonioCalliariFilho. Given what @MarkRansom and you say, the cleanest way to implement your solution is to add this to the if statement: `if abb.strip() in states_list:` This works. Thank all of you for the suggestions - it is quite clear now as to why it wasn't working in its original form!